# Fabric Plugin is ghosted

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, google-fabric

I had install fabric plugin from android market place but it is not clickable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

> To Enable Fabric Plugin please follow this step:

**1. Settings -> Plugins -> Installed**

**2. Click on Fabric for Android Studio**

**3. Click on Enable -> Apply**

**4. Click "OK"**

**5. Restart IDE.**

Please check below image:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is Enable but Not Working

Comment: Do you login with fabric?

Comment: Yes I have a login with fabric

Comment: not working  i have try to uninstall and install to but didn't work

Comment: what is actual problem?

Comment: I want to use fabric plugin to register my app on fabric.io

Comment: Fabric is being shut down, this might be why its not working

Comment: As per your given description which is fabric plugin is not "Clickable", I have given solution which make fabric plugin clickable.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is Working for Enable Fabric